# Trying to run react-native cli on High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Here are the versions I am using:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.64.0
- Xcode 10.1
- cocoapods version: 1.10.1

I keep getting this error whenever I run `react-native run-ios`

**BUILD FAILED**

The following build commands failed:
*CompileC /Users/matthewharrison/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LiveApp2-amxfqqouedceorcarxmrstlitata/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/VirtualEventBase.o /Users/matthewharrison/Desktop/dev/LiveApp2/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/io/async/VirtualEventBase.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)*

Is there something that I am missing? I have done everything I have seen on here with this error. Now I am starting to think it has something to do with my environment. Am I wrong for thinking that? Has anyone successfully ran the current version of react native on High Sierra?

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: updated your Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You are using react-native version 0.64

In react-native version 0.64, you are required to use XCode 12

see this official announcement https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/03/12/version-0.64#major-dependency-version-changes

```
Major Dependency Version Changes

- Dropped Android API levels 16-20.
The Facebook app consistently drops support for Android versions with sufficiently low usage.
As the Facebook app no longer supports these versions and is React Native’s main testing surface, React Native is dropping support as well.
- Xcode 12 and CocoaPods 1.10 are required
- Minimum Node support bumped from 10 to Node 12
- Flipper bumped to 0.75.1
```

Comment: So I would need to find a compatible version of react native and react native cli that fits my system, do you know what versions would work with my system? It has been such a pain dealing with this, I am trying my best to avoid using expo because it does not have the libraries I would need for the app I want to build. If I use the older version of react native and react native cli would an ios 14 user be able to download the app?

Comment: I got it working, I had to use react native version 0.62.0 with my setup

Comment: even react-native 63.3 would function on high sierra and xcode 10.1. yes assuming that you publish your app, any phone with high iOS version would be able to run your app.